# How well analyzed are giant block length ciphers?

Tags: encryption, block-cipher

I have heard about ciphers that have a block length of 256 megabytes. That is huge. How well are they understood by the encryption community?
I'm referring to [PMC Ciphers](https://www.globaliptel.com/eng/content/Backround-Info/Giant-Block-Size-Polymorphic-Cipher.html).

Has anyone used such a cipher in a real world application?

Comment: It's easy to construct a large block blockcipher from a normal block cipher with a factor 2 performance hit. So I see little reason to use dedicated large block blockciphers.

Comment: This website sure looks dodgy. They push large blocks as an advantage without ever giving a reason. They declare that being able to use low-end devices is a downside (it's a downside for password hashing, which isn't what ciphers are for). They demonstrate the insecurity of ECB mode and claim that the underlying cipher is the problem. Their papers aren't peer-reviewed and somehow they claim it as an advantage. All in all, that's a load of snake oil.

Comment: in that image comparison (encrypting a 6 bit grayscale with large patches of same color) is very skewed against AES by using ECB, the PDF only mentions CBC as an afterthought

Comment: Apparently encryption primitives derived from PRP's **must** use padding as they have a fixed block size (??). Stopped reading there. Snake oil and the author is clueless.

Comment: The link does not go directly to any relevant information.

Comment: The link is broken now. Apparently that domain name got reclaimed by the cloud ISP.